# using resource files with parameters

Tags: resources

My question is about resource files (.resx) in c#.(the "strings" part)
I'm using it to store my messages,and I want to know how can we use the "value" of a resource entry with parameters ?!

example :

Name : ShowCellValue
Value : value on cell : ? and row : ? is : ?

and I want to fill the "?" parameters with different values.

Thank you,

Answer (score 6):

You can use string.Format on strings stored in your resource files.

Store ShowCellValue as

```
string showCellValue = "value on cell {0} and row {1} is {2}";
```

Then when you want to use it, just use the ResourceManager:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("resource root name", 
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
MessageBox.Show(string.Format(rm.GetString("showCellValue"), 
    cellName, rowName, cellValue);
```