# Use A Parameter In A .rs Resource File C++ Console

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, resource-files

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537159/using-resource-files-with-parameters) but I'm looking for a **C++** version.

I want to create a **.rs** file with a **DialogBox** that uses a **string as a variable** instead a " " so I can change it in the program.

For example: In

```
DEFPUSHBUTTON   "Hello World", IDOK, 8, 24, 75, 14
```

the `"Hello World"` would become a variable name, which I can *'define'* or *set* in the program.

Why? I'm trying to make a DialogBox, like a **'template'**, and make many instances around the program with **different Text in but same buttons** in them.

Hope my gibberish is understanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The caption text for a control must be a constant string because the resource file is actually compiled separately from your application and has no knowledge of variables defined elsewhere in your program's code.

Resource files do support string tables, but even these require the strings to be constant values. The advantage is that you can modify the resource file without access to the rest of the source code, which makes things like localization possible, even by outside translators.

So you're stuck hard-coding the initial caption of your `DEFPUSHBUTTON`. It can be an empty string or whatever value you want; you just need a placeholder. And you can put all of the possible captions in a string table (which I would recommend), but you cannot link the two using any automated mechanism.

You need to write the code to do this yourself. You could certainly *dynamically* generate resources, but that's quite a bit of trouble. I think the simplest way of doing this is just to create the dialog (using your "template" resource file), retrieve the handle of the controls whose caption text you want to change, and send them a `WM_SETTEXT` message with the new string. In fact, the [`SetDlgItemText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645521.aspx) function will do exactly this for you.

Perhaps that would be easier to explain with some code. Assume that you have a dialog resource defined, including all of your controls. All of the controls you wish to modify will need to have a unique ID assigned to each of them so that you can distinguish between them at runtime. It doesn't matter what the *initial* values you assign in the resource file are, as you're going to be changing them right off the bat. It might look like this:

```
IDD_TEMPLATE DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, xx, xx
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION
CAPTION "Dialog Template"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    CTEXT           "Placeholder text", IDC_MESSAGE, xx, xx, xx, xx
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "Placeholder",      IDOK,        xx, xx, xx, xx
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",           IDCANCEL,    xx, xx, xx, xx
END
```

Then, in your dialog procedure ([`DialogProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469.aspx)), handle the [`WM_INITDIALOG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645428.aspx) message as follows:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK TemplateDialogProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (uMsg)
  {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
      // Load the caption strings you want to use from the string table
      // in the resource file, or get them from wherever you want.
      // These are the "variables" you wanted to use in the question.
      TCHAR* pszMessage;
      LoadString(hInstance,   /* instance handle for app or resource DLL */
                 IDS_MESSAGE, /* ID of the string resource to load       */
                 reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(&pszMessage),
                 0);
      TCHAR* pszOkBtn;
      LoadString(hInstance, IDS_OKBUTTON, reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(&pszOkBtn), 0);
      // ...etc.

      // Set the caption text for each control.
      SetDlgItemText(hwndDlg,     /* handle to the dialog box window */
                     IDC_MESSAGE, /* ID of the control to modify     */
                     pszMessage); /* variable containing text to set */
      SetDlgItemText(hwndDlg, IDOK, pszOkBtn);
      // ...etc.

      // And, if you want to set some other properties, you can do that too.
      // For example, you might set the caption of the dialog itself.
      TCHAR* pszTitle;
      LoadString(hInstance, IDS_DLGCAPTION, reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(&pszTitle), 0);
      SetWindowText(hwndDlg, pszTitle);
      // ...etc.

      return TRUE;  // set the default focus
    }
    // ...process other messages as necessary
  }
  return FALSE;  // we did not process the message
}
```

Comment: I tried only the `SetDlgItemText()` method and it worked great, even gave me some ideas. And I looked up `LoadString()` in MSDN, but didn't quite get what it does and where it gets the string from. Would you explain it with literally **a few** words?

Comment: @Bonnev It loads string resources from your project resource file. This is the same one you defined the dialog resource in. The documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381050(v=vs.85).aspx). You can add the `STRINGTABLE` to your rc file manually, or use Visual Studio's Resource Editor to do it.

Answer (score 1):

While I think Cody Gray's answer is better, there is always the option of creating your dialog template in-memory, and modifying it as you create new instances of the dialog.  I wouldn't recommend it unless you find this kind of thing fun (*I'm* one of those people).  I certainly wouldn't recommend it for what you're asking, but it is technically an option...

[`DialogBoxIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms645457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes a pointer to a structure that is made up of a header ([`DLGTEMPLATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms645394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) that describes the dialog box itself, followed by the specified number of controls ([`DLGITEMTEMPLATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Effectively you can use the above to build a new in-memory dialog template each time you want a DialogBox with different text on the button.  However, that's a little extreme if all you really want to do is change some text, which as Cody says, you can do with `SetDlgItemText`.

If you're *really* curious, [here's an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/29/412577.aspx).

Comment: **Will** see it, but I prefer it to be in a .rs file. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yup, I mentioned this approach but didn't bother to elaborate. Even for me, and I consider myself knowing Win32 programming quite well, creating dialog templates in memory is a lot of work. You absolutely have to have that code wrapped up in a library, or you'll be tearing your hair out. But there are some things where this really is the best option, so it's good to be aware of it.

Comment: Indeed, it's a lot of work for very little gain, but thought it was worth covering. If the dialogs hardly differ then altering the text before showing the box is neater. Generating templates in-memory should probably be reserved for completely dynamic dialogs, the contents of which are only known at runtime.